# recover data from mdf files (ndf being missing)

Tags: sql-server, data-recovery

Our client's server got corrupted and the drives containing NDF and LDF files were gone. The only drive that survived was the one with MDF files.

There were no backups of any sort. They recovered the database, which I know just a gist of, by creating new database (from a old database, I guess) and applied bcp utility to copy data over to the new one. But, they would not release the information how they actually recovered.

So, I was just curious to find how it is possible to recover data from MDF files only, when the NDF files are lost/missing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to restore your database by using <kbd>[sp_attach_single_file_db](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174385.aspx)</kbd> system stored procedure. Something like this...

```
USE [master]
GO

EXECUTE sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='DB_Name',
@physname=N'C:\Path_To_Your_MDF_FILE\DB_Name.mdf'
GO
```

**Edit**

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE DB_Name
ON (FILENAME = N'C:\Path_To_Your_MDF_FILE\DB_Name.mdf') 
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

Comment: i have tried this before...it will not execute without ndf (if the database had ndf file)

Comment: Not the edit one works either. Still looks for ndf file.